# CSS - cover the whole page with semi-trasparent black

Tags: html, css

I have a page with some images (they are characters you can choose) and when they are clicked I want the result in the pictures...what I can't get is to have the semi-trasparent black rectangle covering the whole page...any advice?

Thanks

[image: What I have]

[image: What I want]

Edit: here is the code I tried in the first place, it didn't work because the color was under the images:

```
<body>
<div class = "cover">
<img src="images/1.PNG">
<img src="images/2.PNG">
<img src="images/3.PNG">
<img src="images/4.PNG">
<img src="images/5.PNG">
<img src="images/6.PNG">
<img src="images/7.PNG">
<img src="images/8.PNG">
</div>
</body>
```

With this CSS:

```
.cover {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: show some code...

Comment: Research [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) it will do exactly what you want for viewing images.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a small example. But, as a hint, you need a div that covers the page (and probably holds the card), and set the background to be an rgba with black + semi transparent. Look into lightbox/modal window examples

Comment: Or [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) would also be a good option here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this questions does not show any research effort or any attempt to solve the issue before posting this question on Stack Overflow. There are numerous solutions already available both on Stack Overflow as well as on the wider internet. Stack Overflow is not intended as a first point of call for asking questions about something you have not already researched and attempted to answer of your own volition.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't post my code, but it simply didn't work so I thought it was useless, next time I will include it...I had thought of a solution such as putting a <div> with the opacity property, what I got wrong was i was including the whole set of images in it instead of putting it at the end of the body as suggested below

Answer (score 1):

A quick idea of how you could get this to work. Could then toggle the class "on-top" to whichever card you select.

```css
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
}

.card{
  position: relative;
  display: block-inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.on-top{
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card on-top"></div>
<div class="card"></div>


<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `<div>` element and place it at the bottom of your HTML file, just before the closing `</body>` tag.  Give it the id `cover`.

Then add this CSS

```
#cover { 
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        bottom:0; 
        left:0; 
        right:0; 
        background:#000; 
        opacity:.5; 
 }
```

This should place a semi-transparent black rectangle over the whole page.

When the images are clicked, you need to toggle the visibility of this div, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked, I was putting the <div> around the images, not at the end, that's where I got wrong